# oAuth token in browser history

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am writing a native app which uses oAuth. (my app is the client)
At the moment, my app is native to Windows, but I assume that this problem is the same across all desktop operating systems.

To accommodate the oauth flow: My native app opens a browser tab and directs it to the oauth provider.

I am using a browser and not an embedded webview because many Identity providers (ex: google) block non standard browser implementations. ( They want to prevent automated bots).

My app has a small web-server which it uses to listen for the redirect_url called back from the identity provider. Then my app goes on to use said token to access oauth resources from the provider (ex: gmail)

The problem is: When the identity provider (such as google) redirects back to my app, it returns the access_token to my app in the browser's address bar. As such, this token will then appear in the browser history, which will make it very easy for other native apps (or random users using the browser later) to steal my app's token.

What can I do to mitigate this?

How do I prevent the access_token from the oauth callback from showing up in my browser history?

Comment: 1/ remember that the access token is only valid for 60 minutes, so bing in history should not represent a security threat.  2/ As Gary says, there are two types of app. Web Browser and everything else (server, embedded, desktop, etc) Your app is the latter.

Comment: @pinoyyid doing a token exchange requires a client secret. Is it not unsafe to store a client_secret on an end-user-device? True, I will not have my token stolen from the browser (or middleman), but someone will steal my global "client_secret" from my native app's binary. (Thereby stealing a secret belonging to my entire deployment). I thought that the non-implicit flow was only valid if I had a backend server to store my secrets

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using Implicit Flow which is the main problem:

- Update to Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) so that only a one time use authorization code is returned. Even if an attacker steals it somehow, it will have been used already and the attack will fail.

Another option is to show an Interstitial Page in the browser after login, with a button click to return to your app. As part of that click you can clear the browser tab's history and move to a new location:

```
history.replaceState({}, document.title, redirectLocation):
```

See my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/) for some further details on how this looks.

Comment: I cannot use Authorization. I don't have a server.
The native app is running on the client machine.